# Why transcoding Windows-1252 encoding set to utf-8 is still garbled by using GO

Tags: go, http, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1252

I got a bunch of http requests through traffic recording, and they came to the responseBody with different character set encodings like UTF-8, windows-1252, etc., and I wrote a piece of code that converts the various character set encodings to UTF-8 for identification, However, after I converted it into UTF-8 and saved to csv file, it was still garbled. I printed the converted []byte charset, and it was shown as UTF-8. Can someone help me?

Here's my code for converting:

```
func decodeToUTF8(data []byte) (string, error) {
    detector := chardet.NewTextDetector()
    charsetResult, err := detector.DetectBest(data)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
    }

    log.Println("charset:", charsetResult.Charset)

    var transformer transform.Transformer
    if charsetResult.Charset == "windows-1252" {
        // 如果编码是 windows-1252，需要特殊处理
        transformer = charmap.Windows1252.NewDecoder()
    } else {
        encoding, _ := charset.Lookup(charsetResult.Charset)
        if encoding == nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("error: %v", charsetResult.Charset)
        }
        transformer = encoding.NewDecoder()
    }

    // 使用检测到的编码转换为 UTF-8
    decodedData, _, err := transform.Bytes(transformer, data)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error: %v", err)
    }

    return string(decodedData), nil
}
```

And here's the result after convert to UTF-8:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujwlR.png)

I want any encoding set to output UTF-8

Comment: It is basically impossible to "detect" the encoding. If you do not know the encoding you can _guess_ (which is different to "detect"). Sometimes your guess will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, can I get the encoding from the 'Content-Type' field in the responseHeader and use it to decode?

Comment: And by the way, I filte the response only if there Content-Type is 'application/json'

Comment: Content-Type may or may not contain the encoding. If it does (and is correct): Use it. But application/json by definition/specification is UTF8 only, so I do not understand your question.